# Scrapy and Xpath to extract data from javascript code

Tags: javascript, python, xpath, web-crawler, scrapy

I am in the process of learning and simultaneously building a web spider using scrapy. I need help with extracting some information from the following javascript code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript+gk-onload">

    SKART = (SKART) ? SKART : {};
    SKART.analytics = SKART.analytics || {};
    SKART.analytics["category"] = "television";
    SKART.analytics["vertical"] = "television";
    SKART.analytics["supercategory"] = "homeentertainmentlarge";
    SKART.analytics["subcategory"] = "television";

</script>
```

I wish to extract the category information as television using Xpath. Please help me with the selectors I should use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Selector`'s built-in support for *regular expressions* through [`re()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions):

```
pattern = r'SKART\.analytics\["category"\] = "(\w+)";'
response.xpath('//script[@type="text/javascript+gk-onload"]').re(pattern)
```

Demo (using [`scrapy shell`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html)):

```
$ scrapy shell index.html
In [1]: pattern = r'SKART\.analytics\["category"\] = "(\w+)";'

In [2]: response.xpath('//script[@type="text/javascript+gk-onload"]').re(pattern)
Out[2]: [u'television']
```