# Using scrapy to get data within a script

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy to get the integer values for the field10 and field12 for a given ID within the following script :

```
<script>

    Autoslave.jQuery(function ($) {
        "use strict";
        var map = initMap([

        {"field1": "operational",
        "field2": "operational",
        "field3": "operational",
        "ID": 2,
        "field4": "some text",
        "field5": 48.8732135,
        "field6": 2.3903853,
        "field7": 1,
        "field8": "SPACE",
        "field9": "some text",
        "field10": 4,
        "field10": false,
        "field12": 0}, 

        {"field1": "operational",
        "field2": "operational",
        "field3": "operational",
        "ID": 3,
        "field4": "some text",
        "field5": 48.8592806,
        "field6": 2.3773563,
        "field7": 0,
        "field8": "SPACE",
        "field9": "some text",
        "field10": 2,
        "field11": false,
        "field12": 3},

...

</script>
```

In scrapy shell, I've succeed to get the script text with `response.xpath('//script[14]/text()').extract()`but then I don't know how to select my values within the text, for a defined ID. Any ideas how to this (maybe using regex ?)

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29163395/scrapy-and-xpath-to-extract-data-from-javascript-code

Comment: Do you know what would be the regex pattern in my case? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to extract. What does your xpath return exactly? And how do you want it to look?

Comment: My current xpath returns the text above. For a given `ID`, let's say `2` here,  I want to get the linked `"field10"` and/or `"field12"` values, which are `4` and `0` in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution doesn't use regex but since the script has `json` in it, I would use python's `json` module to get the required field. I will assume that there isn't any other variable except `var map`.

```
script =  ''.join(response.xpath('//script[14]/text()').extract())
json_data = script.split("initMap(")[1].replace("</script>","")[:-1]
data = json.loads('{"data":'+json_data+'}')
fields = data["data"]
for f in fields:
    id = f["ID"]
    field10 = f["field10"]
    field12 = f["field12"]
```

Comment: Thanks ! I think using JSON is a good solution. However I got the following error : TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given) ?

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get the JSON data !
But the line `data = json.loads({"data":json_data})` returns me :
`TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: Updated it. It was happening because `json.loads` takes string or buffer as argument and we were passing a `dict` . Try now. It should works.